# Stop command line process started in C# on Close of Application

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, process

I have started a process in my C# application on a button click event as below,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
private void btnOpenPort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "http-server";
    // startInfo.Arguments = "/C http-server -p 8765";
    this.process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    this.process.Start();                     
}
```

Now, I want to Stop this Command-line process on the close of the application windows. As if I write a command in Command Prompt, I usually press *Ctrl + C* to stop the execution.

**Edit: I have this event, fired when clicked on a close button.**

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Int32 result = DllWrapper.HdsDestroy();
    MessageBox.Show("Destroy result = " + (result == 0 ? "Success" : "Fail"));
}
```

I found a solution on the Internet, SendKeys but I couldn't understand it.
*PS: It might be duplicate of some questions but some of them won't work for me.*

**Thank you in Advance**

Comment: hey @mjwills, I just figured out that `process.Start()` starts two processes a cmd.exe and NodeJs and on `process.Kill()` it kills only the cmd.exe. So the server still running!

Comment: Yes. `startInfo.FileName = "http-server";` using this.

Comment: In that case, find the `nodejs` process and kill it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Thanks to @mjwills for guiding me.*

Later, I figured out that `process.Start()` in this case, started two different processes. One is **cmd.exe** and another is **node.exe**.

`process.Kill()` only kill the **cmd.exe**. So, I have figured it out that I have to find that **node.exe** process and kill it too.

I have two solutions :

**1.** This might stop all the process named **node.exe** but for now, this worked for me.

```
foreach(var node in Process.GetProcessesByName("node"))
{
   node.Kill();
}
```

**2.** As I mentioned in my question, Use `SendKeys.SendWait("^(C)");`.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);
```

Import this dll file for getting the command line window on the foreground. Then I modified the Close button event like this.

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{   
    Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
    IntPtr h = proc.MainWindowHandle;
    SetForegroundWindow(h);
    SendKeys.SendWait("^(C)");          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `process.Kill();` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx), that will stop the associated process.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on whether you're showing a window or not.
If you are showing a window use:

```
process.CloseMainWindow();
```

If you're not, you can search for the process name and close it:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Process Name").First().Kill();
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("Process Name").First().Close();
```

For better results try to put the previous code in a try-catch bloc

Answer (score -1):

Add this line to the constructor of Form:

```
Application.ApplicationExit += (s, ev) => process.Kill();
```

**EDIT**

Use this code:

```
if (process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    process.CloseMainWindow(); // this Closes process by sending a close message to its main window.
else
    process.Kill(); // this kills Hidden window
process.Close(); // Frees all resources that are associated with process.
```

Comment: have a close button click event and tried `process.Kill()` in that event but the process still didn't stop.

Comment: @lazzy_ms: you are not supposed to randomly down-vote every answer if it does not solve your problem. Just don't up-vote it and leave it there.

Comment: I didn't. someone else did.

Answer (score -2):

handle the application exit event and close the process in this event handler.

`public static event EventHandler ApplicationExit`

example:

```
// Attache Handler to the ApplicationExit event.
Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(this.OnApplicationExit);
```

Handler:

```
private void OnApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    try {
        // Ignore any errors that might occur while closing the file handle.
        process.Kill();
    } 
    catch {}
}
```

Comment: have a close button click event and tried this in that event but the process still didn't stop.

Comment: Then there might be some exception during killing the process. can you share the exception log.

Comment: No there is no exception occurring.

Comment: @lazzy_ms: you are not supposed to randomly down-vote every answer if it does not solve your problem. Just don't up-vote it and leave it there.